# Finding Value of a checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox

I am working in **ASP.NET 1.1**.

I am adding a **check box dynamically** with changing count value like this :

```
<INPUT id='btnCheck" + count.ToString() + "' name='btnCheck" + count.ToString() + "' type='checkbox' value='" + row["EmpId"].ToString() + "' Runat='server' Width='50px'>
```

Now I am able to get this -- `id='btnCheck" + count.ToString()`

`value in code behind. But I am not able to get to refer ths ID from code behind and get the value='" + row["EmpId"].ToString() + "'` for this `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add check box like this, you are making html string not a server control, instead use CheckBox class to instanstiate its object

```
CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
```

To add the created checkbox in page control.

```
this.Controls.Add(ch);
```

Comment: Declare the checkbox on class scope.

Comment: Yes..I am able to add the control now..but there is no CheckBox.Value support here..CheckBox.Text is there..which is displaying the text.

Comment: Try, ch.Attributes["value"] = "123";